# Is it allowed for a Native App client to use any random available port in a redirect URI?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm in the process of understanding how to implement OAuth 2.0 native app the right way for Windows. And I've stumbled across this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/blob/master/OAuthConsoleApp/OAuthConsoleApp/Program.cs) written in C#.
But this is what bugs me about this example:

```
// Creates a redirect URI using an available port on the loopback address.
string redirectUri = $"http://{IPAddress.Loopback}:{GetRandomUnusedPort()}/";
```

Everywhere I've read about OAuth 2.0, it's explicitly said that redirect_uri must be pre-registered on OAuth server and can't be dynamic.
Is the example wrong or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the Gary's reply and his [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.3) provided, I've found this piece:

> The authorization server MUST allow any port to be specified at the
> time of the request for loopback IP redirect URIs, to accommodate
> clients that obtain an available ephemeral port from the operating
> system at the time of the request.

In my original post I was confused by the example utilizing a random available port that made redirect-uri dynamic.
But it turns out, the oauth server **must** allow any port of redirect-uri that comes from the client as soon as it's on a loopback interface.

Answer (score 3):

According to [OAuth for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.3) you should be able to register a static redirect URI like this:

- http://localhost/callback

Then at runtime you should be able to use various redirect URLs like this:

- http://localhost:8001/callback
- http://localhost:8002/callback
- http://localhost:8003/callback

I have rarely seen this supported though, and more commonly you need to register three or so specific URLs instead. You need to test for your provider to be sure.